# SMTP Authentication Error with Django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, email, heroku, smtp

I am trying to send emails from my django app using the the gmail smtp servers. The emails are being sent when I run the application on my local server. But I'm getting an SMTP Authentication Error while using it on heroku.

Traceback - [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25456195/)

settings.py -

```
# Email configuration.

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '***************@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '************'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '******************@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

And I have rechecked the account password, also I have **enabled** the **access of less secure apps** from my google account. But still I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/), because gmail smtp has some problem. I too was unable to do using gmail smtp. But it worked perfectly using sendgrid. And this is also free for basic use.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'userpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'asdf@example.com'
```

Comment: The username and userpassword will be the one from the sendgrid right ??

Comment: Yeah just create the account and use the same username and password.

Comment: And what about the `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`

Comment: Will it be my gmail email id, as that's the one i provided on sendgrid while creating an account

Comment: Though that is not required but you can give any email id there, For me I have given `support@kodefork.com.` It will be used to send if sender is not specified.

Comment: If you want custom emailid you can go to zoho and they provide email service for 25 custom emails for free.

Comment: But it is not required though.

Comment: @Anurag-Sharma, Thanks a lot. I feel privileged to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome suggestion! Make sure you create the API key on SendGrid's website and follow the Django instructions here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/django/

Comment: I was using this and now I'm trying to switch to Gmail because Sendgrid's free plan comes with a cap on how many emails you can send in a day - 100 emails per day.

Answer (score 12):

Disabling CAPTCHA for clients
If you are not using 2-factor authentication and you have verified the credentials in your Python source are correct, follow these steps:

1. Login to gmail in your browser
2. Navigate to the [DisplayUnclockCaptcha](http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) page.
3. Click the continue button, and you will see the message

    `Account access enabled Please try signing in to your Google account again from your new device or application.`
4. Run your Python script - your login attempt should be successful.

Comment: Though i know how to make it work but as the error pops up, google also sends a security email mentioning that login attempt from an insecure app. Does that mean that it will work perfectly with HTTPS ??

Comment: I also want to add to your answer that the DisplayUnlockCapatcha only remains active for only 10 minutes i.e, after every 10 minutes you need to enable access.

Answer (score 0):

`Change from mail(@gmail.com) domain to your company domain .`then it will work. we can't use from mail domain @gmail.com,  `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '******************@yourcompanydomain.com'`