# Heroku Django Mail not Sending

Tags: python, heroku, django-rest-framework

I want to send mail with Django-RestFramework and ReactjS .At local machine, sending mail works properly but if i deploy the codes on Heroku, I get always Errors like

> **Object of type NameError is not JSON serializable**  or **SmtpAuthentication Error Object is not Serializable**

Can someone help me please?

Serializers.py

```
class contactSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.CharField()
    subject = serializers.CharField()
    message = serializers.CharField()
   

    def validate(self, data):
        print("data**********", data)
        return data
        
    def save(self):
        email = self.validated_data['email']
        message = self.validated_data['message']
        subject = self.validated_data['subject']
        name = self.validated_data['name']
        cntct= contacts(name=name, email=email,subject=subject, message=message)
       
        send_mail(subject, 'Name :'+name+'\n\n'+email+'\n\n\n\n' +
                      message, email,[email])
        return cntct.save()
```

views.py

```
class contactCreateandMailSend(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = contactSerializer
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = contactSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = serializer.validated_data
        try:
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'sucesss': 'Message has been sent'})
        except Exception as err:
            return Response({'errors': err})
```

Settings.py

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

import dj_database_url

db_from_env= dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),

]
WHITENOISE_MIMETYPES = {
    '.xsl': 'application/xml'
}
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 3
}




EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
# If this is used then `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` will not have any effect
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG=os.environ.get("DEBUG_VAL")
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Response Body

```
TypeError at /contacts/mail/
Object of type SMTPAuthenticationError is not JSON serializable

Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://estate-real-appp.herokuapp.com/contacts/mail/
Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Executable: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path: ['/app/.heroku/python/bin', '/app', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python37.zip', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time: Fri, 11 Dec 2020 03:25:22 +0000
Installed Applications:
['Account',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'drf_yasg',
 'immobilien',
 'listinghouse',
 'contacts',
 'corsheaders']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware']


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 202, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 103, in render
    allow_nan=not self.strict, separators=separators
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/json.py", line 25, in dumps
    return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py", line 67, in default
    return super().default(obj)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

Exception Type: TypeError at /contacts/mail/
Exception Value: Object of type SMTPAuthenticationError is not JSON serializable
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data
```

Comment: The root of these errors have 2 different causes. You need to provide full error trace for each error and perhaps explain what you may think can cause the error. You can also simply search up the error with a keyword 'Heroku' and see what possible solutions are suggested that may apply in your case.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282
 first of all thanks for your response
I have added also response body

By Following link, you can get  the API  and if you want you can try it also!
I think, the problem deal with  send_mail() method or settings with smtp credentials. On local  machine, everything is same, it works but on Heroku not.
**https://estate-real-appp.herokuapp.com/**

Comment: FInally, I found the solution  thanks @Sergey    https://stackoverflow.com/a/56497703/12738618